# Python 3.2 number theory library

Tags: python, primes, modulo

I'm having trouble finding a usable python 3 number theory library. All the libraries I found are written for python version 2, or they're lacking the functionality that I am looking for. I require modular square root function that can handle composite numbers with a known factorization.

I could roll my own, but I assumed that someone else had already solved this problem and it's a relatively routine thing to find.

Comment: Since you are the first one on SO to ask for a modular square root function in Python, the claim that it's "relatively routine thing to find" seems in doubt. ;-)

Comment: I made the assumption and was proven wrong... :-(

Answer (score 1):

This collection of functions have modular square roots. The code looks Python 3 compatible to me. (Closer inspection seems to indicate it's Python 3 only, in fact).

https://github.com/hellman/libnum

If nothing else, it should be a start.

Comment: They don't appear to be. I actually tried this library and even ran it through the 2to3 utility and there were still syntax errors.

Comment: @FooBarrigno It's a metter of running 2to3, renaming `xrange` to `range`, import `reduce` from `functools` and change line 101 of `factorize.py` from `lambda acc, (p, e): p**e` to `lambda acc, p_e: p_e[0]**p_e[1]`. At least with this changes I'm able to import all the modules of the library without errors. The code of the library seems mostly okay, even though some things puzzle me(e.g. why implementing `factorial` when there is `math.factorial` available? ).

Comment: I gave that a shot, but ended up with an error in the primes.py file after the sqrtmod generator executed. If it's worth my while, I may look at porting more of the code over.